# How to change url by click tabs Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing

I use Material Tabs in Angular 2.

How can I change the URL address when clicking on a tab. It is required for history navigation.

Comment: There is an method `updateActiveLink`, without any example how to use

Comment: Couldnt you just on `(click)` trigger a `router.navigate('url')` ?

Comment: What parameters pass to click?

Comment: I tried `this.location.replaceState(path);` but I need to modify current route link, not replace fully

Comment: Nonono dude angular provides a class Router which you can use to change routes. You need to read-up on [Angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `<md-tab-group>`, then tab changes are within the *same* route (=url). If you want the route(=url) to be changed when you click on a different tab, you should use `<nav md-tab-nav-bar>` in combination with `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. This is agnostic to your app's router implementation. (So it works with the standard [Angular router](https://angular.io/guide/router).) Read more about this in the official [tabs documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#tabs-and-navigation).